# filter not returning index value javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a string in js and I want to record the index of each instance of the letter `X`.

I firstly tried using `map` but this just returned `undefined` along with the indexes, which I could have used, but would have required an additional function.

Then I used `filter` instead but unfortunately this is not returning the index. See example below:

```js
const str = 'Hello there XXXX, how are you?';

let indexes = str.split('').filter((letter, index) => {
  if(letter === 'X'){
    return index;
  }
});

console.log(indexes);
```

Comment: A quick look at the documentation will give you the answer why both methods ([`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) won't do what you expect them to do. In this case you're better off with [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: you are misusing `filter()` that will keep or remove element from result based on callback's value. So currently your code returns only 'X' themselves except 'X' in 0th position(if any).

Comment: Filter is not Map

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to fill indexes array by using `forEach` loop:

```
  const str = 'Hello there XXXX, how are you?';

  let indexes = [];
  str.split('').forEach((letter, index) => {
    if(letter === 'X'){
      indexes.push(index);
    }
  });

  console.log(indexes);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead. Here we supply an array as an initial value and push an index to it when the condition is met on an iteration.

```js
const str = 'Hello there XXXX, how are you?';

let indexes = str.split('').reduce((arr, letter, index) => {
  if (letter === 'X') arr.push(index);
  return arr;
}, []);

console.log(indexes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want without having to split the string first:

```
let xes = [];
for (let i = 0; (i = str.indexOf("X", i)) !== -1; xes.push(i++));
```

That finds each "X" with `.indexOf()`, starting from the last position plus 1.

Comment: for loops without a body are always fun :)

Answer (score 1):

Array.filter() creates a new array based on the result of the callback. If the return value in each callback is truthy, a new array with all the elements will be returned. If the return value of each callback in falsy, an empty array will be constructed.

So in this condition,

```
if(letter === 'X'){
  return index;
}
```

the index will be a number > 0 (truthy), so all 'X' will be returned as a new array. If the first character in your input is 'X', the return statement will be `0` which is falsy and that character won't be in the newly constructed array that `filter()` returns.

You could use write something like this instead,

```
const str = 'Hello there XXXX, how are you?';    
str.split('')
  .map((e, i) => e === 'X' ? {allow: true, index: i} : {allow: false})
  .filter(e => e.allow)
  .map(e => e.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), get every character of the string (as any other iterable) and map the index or `-1` for not wanted character. Later filter only wanted indices.

You need two loops for this task, because the first takes the indices and the second filters the intermediate result. Your approach by taking only [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns the elements, but not the index of the the element. After filtering, the indices are gone.

```js
const str = 'Hello there XXXX, how are you?';

let indexes = Array.from(str, (c, i) => c === 'X' ? i : -1).filter(i => i !== -1);

console.log(indexes);
```

Comment: any idea why I can't get the index from the filter function?

Comment: @peterflanagan because that's not what `.filter()` is designed to do. The return value from the callback is treated as a boolean.

Comment: filter does not change the items of the array, jus if the items is in the result set.